# How to define a variable an use it on the jsviews templates?

Tags: javascript, jsviews

I would like to define a unique id, for a html element, that I will have to pass as a parameter of a helper function.

The unique Id is generated correctly with the another helper function (genearteUniqueId) but I can't get it stored in a variable to reuse it and pass it to another function. Does anybody have run into this challenge when using Jsviews?

I tried assigning the generateUniqueId() result to a defined variable as in {{:uniqueId=~generateUniqueId()}} and then pass the uniqueId variable as a parameter  {{:~decorator(uniqueId}} but it didn't work.

```
<div class="graph-row">
   <span class="bar-graph" id="{{:~generateUniqueId()}}" {{:~decorator(outOfPockets[0].paid, outOfPockets[0].total, ~generateUniqueId())}}></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can define your own getUniqueId() which gets the last generated id, along the lines of

```
var cnt = 0, lastId;

var myTmpl = $.templates("#myTmpl"),
  data = {},
  helpers = {
    generateUniqueId: function() {return (lastId = cnt++);},
    getUniqueId: function() {return lastId;},
    decorator: function(id) {return "title=YES" + id;}
  };

myTmpl.link("#page", data, helpers);
```

and write

```
<span id="{{:~generateUniqueId()}}" {{:~decorator(~getUniqueId())}}></span>
```

Alternatively, (though this is better avoided if you are using JsViews data-linking, rather than just JsRender rendering), you can set [allowCode](https://www.jsviews.com/#allowcodetag) to true, with the following approach:

```
$.views.settings.allowCode(true);
var cnt = 0;
function genId() {return cnt++;}
function dec(id) {return "title=YES" + id }
```

and write:

```
<span id="{{*:(theid=genId())}}" {{*:dec(theid)}}>c</span>
```